# Python Vincent world map visualization: How to color each country individually?

Tags: python, visualization, data-visualization, vincent

Does anybody know how to assign individual colors to countries using [vincent's](http://vincent.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) map visualization?

In particular, after loading the world map as follows:

```
world_topo="static/custom/world-countries.topo.json"
geo_data = [{'name': 'countries',
         'url': world_topo,
         'feature': 'world-countries'}]
vis = vincent.Map(geo_data=geo_data, scale=200)
```

I could change the color of the map as follows:

```
vis.marks[0].properties.update.fill.value = '#084010'
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to color each country differently, for example assign white (`#FFFFFF`) to  Antarctica.